# Nuxtjs auth module - token endpoint in auth strategies configuration is never called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs, nuxt-auth

We have two endpoints `/auth` and `/token`. The endpoint `/auth` returns the authorization code that can be used when calling `/token` to get an access token.

Using NuxtJS the `auth` module became the way to go. The login process `this.$auth.loginWith("company")` is working fine as far as I know. I get redirected to the Login Page. I can enter my credentials and when those are valid I get redirected to the configured URL.

Up to that point everything works as expected. The redirect is passing the authorization code as request parameters.

This is what the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/?state=Y6CWcCZanJ&session_state=2c966cd9-5834-4045-9bfb-6aa9f616f841&code=fbabf615-cd5e-4479-818a-6a7ba72de01b.2c966cd9-5834-4045-9bfb-6aa9f616f841.553d562b-c454-4681-83ae-98cd93dbfa90
```

However with this `code` I expect that the `auth` module is automatically calling the `/token` endpoint. But it does not. Why is that?

Do I need to call it explicitly after using `this.$auth.loginWith("company")`? Something like:

```js
this.$auth.loginWith("company");
this.$auth.fetchToken();
```

Or is it done implictly?

This is the configuration in `nuxt.config.js`

```
...
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      company: {
        scheme: "oauth2",
        endpoints: {
          authorization:
            "https://login.mycompany.com/auth/realms/apps/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
          token:
            "https://login.mycompany.com/auth/realms/apps/protocol/openid-connect/token",
          userInfo:
            "https://login.mycompany.com/auth/realms/apps/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
          logout: "http://localhost:3000/logout"
        },
        token: {
          name: "Authorization",
          property: "access_token",
          type: "Bearer",
          maxAge: 1800
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: "refresh_token",
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        },
        responseType: "code",
        grantType: "authorization_code",
        accessType: undefined,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        logoutRedirectUri: undefined,
        clientId:
          process.env.CLIENT_ID ||
          "3004761-241-dab74c5e-ad70-11eb-bea4-4193bd361dc612123",
        scope: ["all"],
        codeChallengeMethod: "S256"
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you forgot to setup `@nuxtjs/axios` or explicitly configure `auth` middleware?

```
// nuxt.config.js
modules: ['@nuxtjs/auth-next', '@nuxtjs/axios'],

router: {
  middleware: ['auth'],
},
```